# What information shoud I write to "intent" column of launcher.db file?

Tags: android

In my application I am editing launcher.db file to put shortcuts on the home screen. This file has table "favorites", and there is column "intent" in this table. What should I write in this column?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, android AOSP Launcher application puts there a URI representation of an `Intent`. For example, if you have an `Intent myIntent`, then in that column you would write:

```
myIntent.toUri(0);
```

At least, that's what AOSP launcher is supposed to write in there.

By the way, how do you manage to write anything in there? It is a private database, accessible via a not-exported `ContentProvider`, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you, your approach does exactly what I need. There are 2 problems anyway - 1) One should use myIntent.toUri(), not myIntent.toUri(0). 2) This method is deprecated. Answering to your question - I am developing a system application for a rooted device, so I am able to write in launcher.db.

Comment: `Intent:toURI()` is the same as calling `Intent:toUri(0)`. You could use any of those, but first is marked as deprecated.